# React Native Picker onPress

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native. In my code I have used react-native picker. When I tap on the picker I want pickerActivity() to be triggered but it gets triggered even before I tap(gets triggered thrice before tapping). Below is my code

```
pickerActivity(){
alert("PICKER PRESSED")
}

render(){
return(
<Picker
  onPress={this.pickerActivity()}
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note: I dont see any `onPress` prop for picker. Instead you can try `onValueChange`. here is the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker#prompt)**.
Here is sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/w7lqnw65kl) to target `onValueChange` event 
 Here goes how we can bind onPress events. 
 `onPress={this.pickerActivity.bind(this)` 
or 
you can use arrow function like 
`onPress={(e)=>this.pickerActivity(e)}`
Advantage of using arrow function is you dont have to worry about `this` context.
See more about events [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

Comment: try alert like `Alert.alert("PICKER PRESSED")` and `import {Alert} from "react-native";`

Comment: @Raj.S you can target you `OnPress` using `onValueChange`.

Comment: @Aravind_S   itemValue and itemIndex are being assigned to onValueChange. I don't know how to target onValueChange again with pickerActivity

Comment: @Raj.S Check this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/w7lqnw65kl..check console for value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177267/discussion-between-raj-s-and-aravind-s).

Comment: @Raj.S if the answer was helpful, the upvote and accept. so that it will be helpful for those who check for the same issue. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `onPress()` function. You can do all this using the `onValueChange`.

Try this instead...

```
pickerActivity = (val) =>{
    this.setState({changedVal: val})
    alert("PICKER PRESSED")
  }

render(){
return(
  <Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.changedVal}
    style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.pickerActivity(itemValue)}>
    <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
    <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
  </Picker>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selected: "key1"
    };
}
onValueChange(value: string) {
    this.setState({
        selected: value
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Content>
                <Form>
                    <Picker
                        note
                           mode="dropdown"
                        style={{ width: 120 }}
                        selectedValue={this.state.selected}
                        onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
                    >
                        <Picker.Item label="Wallet" value="key0" />
                        <Picker.Item label="ATM Card" value="key1" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Debit Card" value="key2" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Credit Card" value="key3" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Net Banking" value="key4" />
                </Picker>
     </Form>
    </Content>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     Call the function inside the onValueChange passing the value as a 
     parameter  
     <RNPickerSelect
              placeholder={{ label: `Estado`, value:null , }}
              style={pickerStyle}
              onValueChange={(value) => [this.setState({ estado: value }), this.cidades(value)]}
              items={
                estados.map((item, index) => {
                  return { label: `${item.state}`, value: `${item.code}` }
                })
             }
           />
```